# Korn Shell .kshrc

Tags: unix, shell, script, ksh, login-script

I'm trying to make the UP arrow to get previous command in Korn Shell but I can't find .kshrc file in my $HOME directory. I know it is hidden but even ls -al doesn't show it. What should I do?

Comment: You probably don't have one. Just make your own using `touch` or an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.kshrc` does not exist just create one.

`.kshrc` is a text file. Its name is `.kshrc`

One way to create it is open up your favourite text editor and save a file to your home directory called `.kshrc`

Comment: how can I create it? what type of file is it?

Comment: @CuriousGuy see edit. But its just a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it in your home folder. in terminal , go to your home folder and type following command

```
touch .kshrc
```